# How do you address cases in modular arithmetic where the input is greater than the modulus?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm not sure how well I'm wording this, but I was wondering how you address cases in modular arithmetic when you plug in a number greater than the modulus, e
g. $\sqrt{8} \pmod{5}$. If you leave $8$ as it is, and square root it, you get $\approx2.828$. If you mod $8$ before doing anything, you get $\sqrt{3} \pmod{5}$, which is $\approx1.782$
These are clearly different answers, so which one do you go with? Do you mod the input before or after you apply expressions to it?

I hope this question was worded well enough, I was just confused how you would handle that (and I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something simple here).

Comment: It's unclear what $\sqrt 8 \pmod 5$, means.  You might mean a solution to $x^2\equiv 8\pmod  5$ but which solution you might call $\sqrt 8$ isn't clear (note that there is no solution in this case, but in principle there could have been multiple solutions).

Comment: Usually, modulo is only applied to integers. To extend this to $r\mod n$ with positive real $r$ you could subtract the largest multiple of $n$ not exceeding $r$ from $r$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I figured it was just me not understanding modular arithmetic. That makes sense why it would be ambiguous and you wouldn't really say it like that

Comment: Besides the already posted comments, which I agree with, there is another flaw in your analysis.  You assumed that because $8 \equiv 3\pmod{5}$ that therefore $\sqrt{8} \equiv \sqrt{3} \pmod{5}$.  Ignoring that modular arithmetic is normally only applied to integers, in general $a \equiv b \pmod{c} \iff ~c ~| (a - b)$.  While $5 ~| ~(8-3)$, it is not the case that $5 ~| ~\left(\sqrt{8} - \sqrt{3}\right).$

Comment: Re previous comment, if $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, it is true that $a \equiv b\pmod{c} \implies a^k \equiv b^k\pmod{c}.$  However, the *reverse implication* does not necessarily hold.  For example $\left(2^2\right) \equiv \left(3^2\right) \pmod{5}$, while it is not the case that $2 \equiv 3\pmod{5}.$